# Redirecting input to an executable from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, redirect

How do you redirect input to an executable from inside VBA? Specifically, why does the code below not work?

```
ChDir theRightDirectory
Set WshShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "runme < start.txt", 1, True
```

Or

```
RetVal = Shell("runme < start.txt", vbNormalFocus)
```

`runme.exe` does start up all right, but the input is not redirected and has to be type in manually in the command window. Also tried:

```
RetVal = Shell("type start.txt | runme.exe", vbNormalFocus)
```

Piping the output of `type start.txt` into `runme.exe` just plain returns a “file not found” error.

Yet when I type those various commands directly at the command line, they all work.

Comment: Do you run anything else at the command line before you execute the commands that include the `|` or the `<`?

Comment: No, nothing else is run before, or after.

Comment: Do you get the same result when you specify the full path for executable and the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer a more general part of your question. You asked:

> Specifically, why does the code below not work?
>   `WshShell.Run "runme < start.txt", 1, True`

The reason the code does not work as you expect is because the shell of WScript.Shell is not the same as the shell of cmd.exe. In particular, **it does not do redirects or pipes**.

If you were able to debug the runme process you would see that it has been passed two arguments, `<` and `start.txt`

As previously answered, there are two ways to fix this:

- feed the WScript.Shell StdIn directly and remove your redirect

  `set oExec = WshShell.exec(cmdLine)`
  `oExec.StdIn.Write "some input for the first prompt" & vbCrLf`
- run the DOS shell instead of runme, let it interpret the rest of the commandline, including the redirect

  `WshShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /C runme < start.txt", 1, True`

Comment: This answer is 5½ years late but the extra explanation actually adds value to the existing answers! Though note, the intent was to pipe things in, i.e. equivalent to `StdIn`, not `StdOut`, as should be apparent from [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1899704/119775) to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the support, and well spotted. I've plucked the wrong line from your own answer, should have used the StdIn.Write instead. Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Execute the command this way:

```
WshShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /C runme < start.txt", 1, True
```

That way it will run it through the command line interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

I've been made aware of this solution: No need to write the input to start.txt; input can just be fed directly to the input stream. (My question should have made clear that this is also an option.) A bonus is that the user can get feedback from the output stream.

```
Set WshShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.CurrentDirectory = theRightDirectory
Set oExec = WshShell.exec("runme.exe")

' Write to the input stream
oExec.StdIn.Write "some input for the first prompt" & vbCrLf & _
                  "some more input" & vbCrLf 

' The output stream can be shown to the user, e.g.
sOutput = oExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
MsgBox (sOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably shelling out to a different folder than you expect.

You may have to change directory using `CHDIR` to the appropriate folder, or qualify your file names using the entire or relative path.

Comment: I do use ChDir to set the appropriate directory. `runme.exe` and `start.txt` are both in the same folder. Edited question to reflect this.