# How to automate PuTTy from Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, putty

I have been trying to automate the following sequence of steps in puTTy via VBA from Excel

1. Login to putty
2. execute a command
3. copy the result from putty and paste it in excel.

So far I have written the code for logging into the server by initiating the putty Application.(Refer the code below)

```
Sub Putty()
  Dim TaskID As Long
  TaskID = Shell("path/putty.exe servername", vbNormalFocus)
  AppActivate TaskID, True
  SendKeys "username"
  SendKeys "{ENTER}"
  SendKeys "password"
  SendKeys "{ENTER}"
  '---- Here i need to execute a command for eg: "ls -l" and copy the result into Excel
End Sub
```

Can you please give some idea about how to execute a command after this step and to copy the result from PuTTy to Excel?

Comment: Does putty have an API that you could reference instead of trying to use `SendKeys`?

Comment: Hi @DavidZemens I really dont have any idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Plink](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) instead of the main Putty application. Plink is putty designed for the command-line.

Look into shell redirection, answers such as [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899704/2250183).

The basic idea is you can create a WScript.Shell object, run plink.exe using it, then write to StdIn and read from StdOut. StdIn is like typing text into a console window and StdOut is what gets displayed to the user in said console window.

Comment: Hi @AndASM, thanks for the reply.I have seen the same suggestions previously in other sites, but i have some administrative restrictions on using the plink.
So this means is it not possible to do with putty.exe?

Comment: To a limited extent it can be done with putty.exe, through the methods of doing so are fragile and prone to breaking. Many of the ways you'd do this are likely blocked if you can't run plink.exe. If the connection you are opening is telnet not ssh, I'd open the connection directly from VBA and skip the external program. If it is ssh, reimplementing all the encryption yourself is prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a log file in putty and watch that log file as you go. It's not the best way to do it, but without admin rights it is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It would run better if you add application wait timer in the script, sendkeys is not very reliable function.