# VBA Excel code using echo y with PLink

Tags: excel, vba, plink

**WARNING: **PLEASE MAKE SURE THAT YOU DO NOT USE THIS APPROACH IF YOU ARE WORKING WITH UN-TRUSTED DEVICES/IP's.** You do not want to automatically cache Ssh Host Keys which are unknown to you. Do take care.

The purpose of my code is to run ssh through `plink.exe` from VBA Excel for a given list of IP's. I am just checking for SSH connectivity and IP's list is dynamic.

I am trying to pass `y` when running ssh using `plink.exe`. The reason for `y` is because first time PLink (PuTTY) asks for caching the IP.

`Echo y` does that automatically from command prompt and runs fine as below.

```
C:\>echo y | Users\Admin\Desktop\plink.exe -ssh 10.0.0.1
```

The command passes `y` and the IP is cached which makes my code automated and the code cycles through the whole list.

I am unable to execute that same command in VBA excel (which is where the tool is) and would need guidance in how to implement it. Please suggest where I am going wrong.

```
Dim strShellCommand As String
Dim filename As String
Dim Run As String
Dim a As String
Dim b As String

filename = Sheet1.Cells(8, 2).Value
a = "echo y |"
b = "-ssh"

' Comments!!
' filename from cell = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\plink.exe"
' echo y | C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\plink.exe -ssh 10.0.0.1
' strCompaddress is any IP

Run = a & " " & filename & " " & b & " " & strCompAddress

Set osh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oEx = osh.Exec(Run)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to circumvent the verification of the SSH host key. It's there [by purpose for your own security](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter2.html#gs-hostkey):

> This is a feature of the SSH protocol. It is designed to protect you against a network attack known as *spoofing*: secretly redirecting your connection to a different computer, so that you send your password to the wrong machine. Using this technique, an attacker would be able to learn the password that guards your login account, and could then log in as if they were you and use the account for their own purposes.

---

Use the `-hostkey` switch instead to provide a fingerprint of the expected host key.

> [3.8.3.20](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey) **`-hostkey`: manually specify an expected host key**
>
> This option overrides PuTTY's normal SSH host key caching policy by telling it exactly what host key to expect, which can be useful if the normal automatic host key store in the Registry is unavailable. The argument to this option should be either a host key fingerprint, or an SSH-2 public key blob. See [section 4.20.2](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-kex-manual-hostkeys) for more information.
>
> You can specify this option more than once if you want to configure more than one key to be accepted.

Note that the `-hostkey` switch was introduced in PuTTY/PLink 0.64.

---

If you use your code to test connectivity, why do you need to accept the host key? The mere fact that the server was able to present the host key is proof of the connectivity.

---

If you really use your code to cache the host keys, so that *"they don't have the click 'yes' for every IP to cache it, "* **do not**. That's absolutely unacceptable. Not only that you break your own security. You deliberately break security of other users that will unknowingly trust any host key that you blindly accepted.

The only correct way to pre-cache the host keys is by importing the known host keys to the registry.

Export **personally verified** (I mean it) host keys from your registry to a file like `SshHostKeys.reg`:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys]
"rsa2@22:example.com"="0x23,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"
```

and import them on the target machine.

For example using:

```
reg import SshHostKeys.reg
```

---

If you really **do not care about a security**, for example because you are connecting within a private network, use:

```
Run = Environ("COMSPEC") & " /c echo y | " & filename & " -ssh " & strCompAddress
```

(assuming a path to `plink.exe` in `filename`)

To make an input redirection working, you have to run the process via shell interpreter (`cmd.exe`). The environment variable `COMSPEC` points to it (typically `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`).

See also [Redirecting input to an executable from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1860563/850848).

Comment: I get your point but I am not sending any log-in information and the code is terminated on the first sight of access to device. I take 'login as' as an indicator of SSH accessibility. This is automated so if the tool is used on some other workstation then they don't have the click 'yes' for every IP to cache it.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the whole scope of this. 
These are management IP's for known devices which are inside a very well secured network (L7 & L4 filtering, IPS/IDS devices, NAT enabled etc.). The testing tool is internal to a very responsible team and the IP's aren't dynamic, only the list is.
Without knowing the whole scope of things, you can't make claims. This  was a very naive question that I had but I think you might have deterred any future responses by being this aggressive.

Comment: TLDR: See a solution in my edited answer. | Well, you should have noted these constraints in your question. Because no one sane will post an answer that purposelessly breaks any security. While it might help you, it would do a bad to loads of anonymous readers that will copy & paste the answer without understanding what they are doing. With your constraints, your question would be closed a duplicate of [redirecting input to an executable from Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1860563/850848).

Comment: That is what I needed and it works really as I needed. Thanks for the complete response along with the security consideration. I apologize for not explaining my position before and I would make a point of making myself clear before asking future questions, especially which deals with security.