# Host key authentication without giving "y" from Windows command line

Tags: batch-file, windows-console, plink

I used `plink -pw password ec2-user@10.0.0.0` from local windows command line.

It asked for **Host key confirmation y/n** 
[image]

How I can automatically give "y" from plink command?

I used `echo Y| plink -pw password ec2-user@10.0.0.0`, but it is not worked.

Comment: OS you are using is Windows? why I see something like linux command down there ?

Comment: `plink` should not ask you again for the same remote after you choose `y`. Do you want to add remotes using a script? The fingerprint should be checked, it’s a security measure.

Comment: @minhhn2910 Can you be more specific? [`plink` is a Windows binary](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#7.1), `echo` and pipe (`|`) can be used on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Does it work if you use a lower case y instead of a capital Y?

Comment: If plink.exe reads input directly from the console, then an `echo` to its stdin will be ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel code using echo y with PLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335508/vba-excel-code-using-echo-y-with-plink)