# How to save time for using plink in VBA

Tags: vba, plink

My VBA codes below shows the template about how to control my host via plink

```
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
for i = 1 to 1000
   wsh.Run("cmd.exe /c plink -ssh 192.168.100.xx -l root -pw xxxx command", 0, True)
   Sleep 1000
next i
```

If I have to get information from host via plink.exe every second, it is necessary to execute "wsh.Run("cmd.exe /c plink -ssh 192.168.100.xx -l root -pw xxxx command", 0, True)" every time, which wastes time in opening shell and  executing plink.exe and then close it all each round. Is there a way to save the time, which means that to open shell and execute plink.exe once and keep plink.exe listening my command until loop ends?

Comment: This question/answer ([redirecting input to an executable from Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1899704/119775)) may give you what you need; it shows how to interact with an executable via WScript.Shell.

Comment: ... but on second thought, it isn't clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Can you show an example of how you would do what you want, manually at the command prompt? Once that's clarified, it will be easier to figure out how to automate it.

Comment: I revised my question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at Chip Pearsons solution, Shell and Wait.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx

> The ShellAndWait function calls Shell and then waits for the Shell'd process to terminate. You can specify an interval after which the function times out and returns to the caller. The declaration of ShellAndWait is as follows: