# Programmatically execute .bat file in Access 2016

Tags: vba, shell, ms-access

I would like to execute a bat file from Access 2016. 
This code opens the bat file: `Shell "cmd /c ""Desktop\mtwo3.bat"", vbHide"`
However, the bat file requires for the user the press any key on a keyboard. Is there a way to accomplish this programmatically?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting input to an executable from Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860563/redirecting-input-to-an-executable-from-excel-vba)

Comment: tried a couple of ways but still can't get it to execute the prompt.