# Coding '<' from CMD in .NET

Tags: vb.net, shell, file, arguments

I would like to pass the input of a txt-File to an application in VB.NET.
Manually it would be something like

```
C:\file.exe -param < textfile.txt
```

Now I want to implement this part in VB.Net.
I've tried the following options:

```
Process.Start(filepath, "-param < test.txt")
```

also tried

```
ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "-param < test.txt"
```

or shell nothing seems to work for me.

Do you have an idea what I can do to pass the content of a file?

Best greetings

Comment: Your example seems to be to call `file.exe < textfile` ... but your other examples more look like `file.exe -param < textfile` ... so, could using "-param" cause that problem? Then "nothing seems to work" is not a helpful description of your problem. What exactly happens; and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: No that's not the problem, I've just forgot to mention the parameter in my example, sry

Comment: And I didnt think through. Your problem is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860563/redirecting-input-to-an-executable-from-excel-vba ... simply spoken: you can't pipe when making such kind of shell exec calls. Instead, **your code** has to use some programmatic means to **write** that text file into some stream that is seen as stdin to the invoked app. I am not a VB expert; so I hope the above link gives at least enough guidance for you to figure the solution.

Comment: Here is a C# answer for the problem noted by GhostCat - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850802/piping-in-a-file-on-the-command-line-using-system-diagnostics-process

Comment: Alright I got it working until I need to pass a password to the application. Which is represented as ********* in the tool. If I pass the password-string using writeline (how I passed my username and other information) the program doesn't respond to my input.